# Young adult book with a black flocked cover; late 1990s early 2000s

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult

We think the book was part of a series. The first book had a black flocked cover, so it had a soft feel like a velvet fabric. Possibly with a gold castle on the front with stars coming up from it. It was a young adult book, it involved magic.

We think there was a dark green sequel, flocked cover again. Possibly with a silver inlay design this time instead of gold.

Memories of a possible plot include a family, Addams Family vibes, and possibly a squid in a cave at some point....but honestly we read so many that we could be jumbling plots.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  So this was a hardcover then?  Standard size?  Do you recall any character or place names?

Comment: Hi, thank you for the welcome  Yes both books were hardbacks, standard size. Frustratingly we can't remember any specific names, it was around 20 years ago that we read them. I think we're just really hoping someone will recognise the cover description and have an aha moment!

Comment: Hm, I think I know the series you mean... Need to try and remember what it's called, though...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Could this be the "[Pure Dead](https://www.goodreads.com/series/81880-pure-dead)" series by Debi Gliori? The first book in the series has a purple velvety cover rather than black, but does have the castle on it you remember:

[image]

Interestingly, it's the paperback version that had the gold and stars you remember (no flock effect here):

[image]

Other entries in the series did indeed have different colours. The third in the series has the green cover:

[image]

Comment: Oh my goodness oh my goodness! Those are the ones! You're incredible, that was so fast, I knew it was a good idea to post here. Thank you so much ❤️❤️❤️

Answer (score 1):

The "[Pure Dead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_Dead_series)" series by Debi Gliori?

Comment: Yes thank you so much! What a fantastic community, so fast. My brother has been trying to work it out for two years and finally involved me yesterday, he's going to be kicking himself  Thank you!

Comment: Can you explain why your answer is correct?

Comment: Their answer is correct because they accurately named the book title and the author that I was looking for, with a link to the Wikipedia page describing the plot. Also I didn't realise you could only mark one answer as correct, which seems unfair! 